# Php file works on server but not when deployed

Tags: php, linux, server, apache2

I have PHP scripts to run for website but it does not work in deployment.
when files run using (php filename.php) shows correct output on shell but not working when called via webpage using htttp:example.com/filename.php

I could see this in error log

```
[cgi:error] [pid 19938] [client 132.186.22.181:55166] AH01215: (13)Permission denied: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/infophp.php' failed
```

and webpage shows

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at root@localhost to inform
>   them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed
>   just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

I have tried both but gives same error.

```
<?php 
echo "hello world";
?>

<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

i should be able to see executed script when called with 
http:/example.com/file.php

Comment: it seems you don't have permission to deploy file in specific folder locations

Comment: Seems more like an OS problem (user and permissions issues) rather than a PHP script problem. If you have a `Linux` environment, try and check if your user is part of the `www-data` or that you have the `www-data` user attributed to your project folder

Comment: `/var/www/cgi-bin/infophp.php` is a file of yours?

Answer (score 0):

please check the permission of the file after deployment

1. either the user doesn't have permission to access from public
2. the file may be read only

   chmod 644

   or chmod -R 777   {worst case}